# how can i connect spark to an android application?

Tags: android, python, apache-spark, flask, cherrypy

i want to create an android application which makes predictions, I already have my spark's code using python and I ve already Building a Web API around my Engine using Flask and runing the server with spark using cherrypy,
The question is how can I connect cherrypy to my android application?
Now i used just spark-submit

```
~/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master local --total-executor-cores 14 --executor-memory 6g --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0 myserver_file.py
```

which gives me :

```
INFO:cherrypy.error:[31/Mar/2018:19:31:46] ENGINE Serving on http://0.0.0.0:5432
[31/Mar/2018:19:31:46] ENGINE Bus STARTED
INFO:cherrypy.error:[31/Mar/2018:19:31:46] ENGINE Bus STARTED
```

so I can get the results on `http://0.0.0.0:5432`, But I want get the result on my android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well can you please try running the server application using the actual IP of your server (i.e. 192.168.103.67 etc.) and then try it from your android application ? Can you make sure that the android device is connected to the machine in same LAN connection ?